# Unable to send more than 60 characters using BluetoothSocket from Android to Arduino

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I'm creating an android application to search and pair a Bluetooth device and send a long string(500 characters) to it.
Everything seems good until I try to write a string with a length more than 60 characters. If I send a string of length 100, the Arduino only receives 60-70!.. It varies for every transmission.
What am I doing wrong? Do i have to implement thread to send a transmission from Android?

The code used in Android to send the string:

```
String a="iedcnifnchiehwixhnrihirhiwhxrithwthwcmwhirhhxtihrihix";//Some string more than 60 characters in length.
btSocket.getOutputStream().write(a.toString().getBytes());
```

The code used in Arduino to receive the characters:

```
while(myserial.available() > 0)
{command = ((byte)myserial.read());
if(command == ':')
{
break;
}
else
{
string += command;
}
Serial.print(string);
}
```

Im using an arduino UNO. The bluetooth module(HC 06) is connected to software serial.

Comment: Maybe arduino is too slow, or maybe the two baudrate generators are not synchronized enough. after all, 100 bytes are 1000 bits, so with a 0.05% clock difference you will have problems. IMHO the best solution is to send them in "packets" of 40-50 bytes, then wait for a very small amount of time (e.g. half a byte length) and then send the next bytes. You won't notice the delay, and you will allow them to resync

Comment: i think packets might work. But i want the string to be transmitted in a single transmission.  Anyway let me try sending packets and check if there is a huge delay involved there! Thanks :)

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "single transmission"? you won't receive them as a single transmission, but as "chunks", so there is no difference in the receiving part. And as for the sending... There is very little work to manage it :P

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is not the Arduino being slow 
some delay may be good if we are sending long texts
but even at 9600 baud rate we can send/receive 9600 bits
i have actually done this using a thread separate for  for Bluetooth connection and communication 
try using a different baud rates and see what happens
also if you are using Arduino UNO
try same code with an Arduino Mega

Comment: i tried changing the Baud rate for the HC 06, but still no success. i dont have a mega right now to check with it.

Comment: can you show you code in more detail.all i can sse here is 2 lines so its hard to see whats wrong

Comment: I have same issue but mine is reverse of above, android application can not receive string more than 70 size of string (70 chararcter). First it does but after few minutes of time it doesn't receive any string

Comment: Ping if you've any solution for this